# Schema name not displaying in vs2010 tool sqldatasource

Tags: visual-studio-2010, adventureworks

I'm pretty new to all this so I may be asking a stupid question. I have just installed sql server express 2012. I have installed the Adventureworks db. When using the sqldatasource tool in vs2010 I get the table names but not the schema name. E.G. Production.Products. I only get the table name Products. Therefore causing an error when running the script.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the default schema is "dbo".

In SQL Server on Left hand side, click on database > Adventureworks > Tables
you could see schema name there.

Comment: Yes, thats the point. In sql server they are visible. In vs2010 using the data tool sqldatasource they are not. So if I choose a table from the list provided in that tool, for example Products, the script fails as it expects Production.Product as named in the db in sql server. The question is if there is a way to display the schema name in the tool so it works properly.